# Encrypting password in mysql using query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app which creates user and stores it in the identities table. I saw that it uses Devise gem and stores password in mysql like this

```
original password: passphrase
encrypted value stored in mysql table: $2a$10$isSx/Z1DRaPJKETkeph/Ie.C5BDTls4g/AhVUHvsODIevtZEazJYm
```

is there a way I can use mysql Update query to update this password. I want to enter original password in query and it should store in encrypted form. I tried ENCRYPT etc. but those are using a different algorithm, not the one which devise is using.

Comment: Also a bad idea to do it in a MySQL query and plain password could be visible in slowquery log / processlist / server logs  and other location i might forgot to mention here If MySQL would support bcrypt (Blowfish)..

Answer (score 0):

Those passwords are actually hashed rather than encrypted. Based on the prefix, this is the bcrypt algorithm version 2a with a cost parameter of 10.

MySQL does not support hashing with bcrypt. You should hash passwords in your application. Devise does this with the `bcrypt` gem.